# conflict between User and user.socialaccount in django-allauth

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have done this tutorial as it explained [here](http://techstricks.com/django-allauth-tutorial-step-by-step/):

and [here](http://techstricks.com/django-allauth-tutorial-access-extra-data/)

but there is some points that i can not understand.

When i log in using a facebook account i can get access also easily to my admin page and i want it to be happened (because it is not secure), so is there a way to fix that ?

If i want to bring that registred user to another template, i can do it only whith direct_to_template method in my url dispatcher, here is an example:
`url(r'^tags$', direct_to_template, {'template' : 'user.html' })`,

is there another way to do it.

Finally to be more clear, here is some snippets of my project:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
#All Auth URLS
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
url(r'^accounts/profile/', direct_to_template, { 'template' : 'profile.html' }),
#nav urls
url(r'^$','fb.views.home', name="home"),
url(r'^tags$', direct_to_template, {'template' : 'tags.html' }),
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
return render_to_response("base.html", locals(), RequestContext(Context))
```

**base.html**

.....

```
{% block body %}
{% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ user.username }}  <p> you are logged in </p>
    <p><a href="/accounts/logout/" >Logout </a></p>
  {% else %}    
    <p> you are not authenticated :  </p>
    <a href="/accounts/facebook/login/" >Login with Facebook </a>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
{% endblock body %}
```

...

**profile.html**

```
...
{% block content %}

{% if user %}

<h1>Welcome, {{user.first_name}}</h1>
<p>Following is the Extra information that facebook has provided to allauth:</p>
{% for account in user.socialaccount_set.all %}
    <p>First Name: {{ account.extra_data.first_name }}</p>
    <p>Last Name: {{ account.extra_data.last_name }}</p>
    <p>Profile Link: <a href="{{ account.extra_data.link }}">{{ account.extra_data.link   }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}

<a href="/tags">  Go to tags</a>

{% endblock content %}
{% endblock body %}
```

**tags.html**

```
{{user.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url}} <br/>
{{user.socialaccount_set.all.0.uid}} <br/>
{{user.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_provider_account }} <br/>
```

Finally thanks in advance for your help .

Comment: you want to take your user to another page?

Comment: you can write a function into your views file for that particular url instead of using direct_to_template

Comment: Yes i want to take that user to another page. could you please show me   how to write that function in my views file ?  also, that logged in user could have access to my admin page, how could i prevent that ?

Answer (score 0):

The secrect is:

After logging in, the user was hiding in the request object, so view shoukd be like this:

```
def home(request):
    user = request.user
    return render_to_response("base.html", locals(), RequestContext(Context))
```

Now, the problem is resolved, but i wonder why the Context User object was anounymous.

i am asking this question because that last user object woiuld have the same value of the request user in a simple authentication